# I can get all $_POST data except for one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to input a record into my database. I can get all data except for one  ['inputPicture'](which is the picture file name)

I've already tried using var_dum($_POST) and print_r($_POST) so I am sure that I cannot get anything from 'inputPicture'

This is what I get from both of them:

```
Array ( [inputFirstName] => Charlie [inputLastName] => Horse [inputContactNumber] => 09154447896 [inputAddress] => Candy Mountain [inputEmailAddress] => charlie@candymountain.com [action] => )
```

Here is my view code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('Contacts/addcontact'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">First Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Last Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Contact Number</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputContactNumber" placeholder="Contact Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Address:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputAddress" placeholder="Address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Email Address:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputEmailAddress" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">Picture:</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="inputPicture"></br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function addcontact(){
    $first_name = $this->input->post('inputFirstName');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('inputLastName');
    $contact_number = $this->input->post('inputContactNumber');
    $address = $this->input->post('inputAddress');
    $email_address = $this->input->post('inputEmailAddress');
    $image_url = $this->input->post('inputImage');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputFirstName', 'First Name', 'required|max_length[35]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputLastName', 'Last Name', 'required|max_length[35]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputContactNumber', 'Contact Number', 'required|exact_length[11]|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputAddress', 'Address', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputEmailAddress', 'Email Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[255]|valid_email');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $data['title'] = 'Address Book';
        $data['contacts_info'] = $this->contacts_model->getContacts();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        redirect();
    }
    else{
        if(!isset($_POST['inputImage'])){
            $this->contacts_model->addContactsNoPic($first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address);
        }
        else{
            $image = 'assets/images/' . $image_url;
            $this->contacts_model->addContacts($first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address, $image);
        }

        $data['title'] = 'Address Book';
        $data['contacts_info'] = $this->contacts_model->getContacts();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        redirect();
    }
}
```

I have a similar method which is 'update'. It works perfectly fine. I tried copy pasting my code from the update to my addContact method but it still doesnt work.

Here is my view code for Update:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('Contacts/update'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group hidden">
                          <label for="usr">ID</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputID" id="id">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">First Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputFirstName" id="firstname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Last Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputLastName" id="lastname">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Contact Number</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputContactNumber" id="contactnumber">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Address:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputAddress" id="address">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="usr">Email Address:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputEmailAddress" id="emailaddress">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">Picture:</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="inputPicture" id="picture"></br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

and here is my controller

```
 public function update(){
    $first_name = $this->input->post('inputFirstName');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('inputLastName');
    $contact_number = $this->input->post('inputContactNumber');
    $address = $this->input->post('inputAddress');
    $email_address = $this->input->post('inputEmailAddress');
    $image_url = $this->input->post('inputPicture');
    $id = $this->input->post('inputID');
    var_dump($_POST);exit;  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputFirstName', 'First Name', 'required|max_length[35]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputLastName', 'Last Name', 'required|max_length[35]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputContactNumber', 'Contact Number', 'required|exact_length[11]|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputAddress', 'Address', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputEmailAddress', 'Email Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[255]|valid_email');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $data['title'] = 'Address Book';
        $data['contacts_info'] = $this->contacts_model->getContacts();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        redirect();
    }
    else{
        if(!isset($_POST['inputPicture'])){
            $this->contacts_model->updateContactNoPic($id, $first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address);
        }
        else{
            $image = 'assets/images/' . $image_url;
            $this->contacts_model->updateContact($id, $first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address, $image);
        }

        $data['title'] = 'Address Book';
        $data['contacts_info'] = $this->contacts_model->getContacts();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        redirect();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have gone through their manuals https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html --- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html - It has its own uploading class.

Comment: I was wondering, why does $_POST work with my inputPicture in my update method while it doesn't in my addcontact method?

Comment: Probably out of luck, since as @Fred-ii- said, CodeIgniter has its own file handling methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because contents of `input type=file` sent by GET/POST methods from HTML to PHP are stored inside the superglobal variable `$_FILES` and not `$_POST` (unless you don't define `enctype` property of the `form` tag as `"multipart/form-data"`, which then causes the filename to be passed as a string to GET/POST).

If you `var_dump($_FILES)`/`print_r($_FILES)` you'll see an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php1485.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1073054
        )
)
```

**OBS:** be sure to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as property of your form and `file_uploads` set to `on` in your php.ini file.

Comment: I tried print_r($_FILES); but it shows an array. How can I get the filename only?

Comment: With `$_FILES['name']` :)

Comment: And if you wanna move the **real file** to another folder where you'll store uploaded files, read about the [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function

Comment: They do have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` Alan.

Answer (score 0):

use $_FILES['inputPicture']

```
public function update(){
$first_name = $this->input->post('inputFirstName');
$last_name = $this->input->post('inputLastName');
$contact_number = $this->input->post('inputContactNumber');
$address = $this->input->post('inputAddress');
$email_address = $this->input->post('inputEmailAddress');
//$image_url = $this->input->post('inputPicture');
$image_url = $_FILES['inputPicture'];
$id = $this->input->post('inputID');
var_dump($_POST);exit;  
$this->form_validation->set_rules('inputFirstName', 'First Name', 'required|max_length[35]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('inputLastName', 'Last Name', 'required|max_length[35]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('inputContactNumber', 'Contact Number', 'required|exact_length[11]|numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('inputAddress', 'Address', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[255]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('inputEmailAddress', 'Email Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[255]|valid_email');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $data['title'] = 'Address Book';
    $data['contacts_info'] = $this->contacts_model->getContacts();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
    redirect();
}
else{
    if(!isset($_FILES['inputPicture'])){
        $this->contacts_model->updateContactNoPic($id, $first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address);
    }
    else{
        $image = 'assets/images/' . $image_url;
        $this->contacts_model->updateContact($id, $first_name, $last_name, $contact_number, $address, $email_address, $image);
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Address Book';
    $data['contacts_info'] = $this->contacts_model->getContacts();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
    redirect();
}
```

}